# ROS Answers SE migration: TF frame error

Tags: navigation, odometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, all,

I am trying to set up a simple TF tree to convert incoming odometer data.
however, the listener doesn't seem picking up anything at all. the tf_monitor shows no frame either.

```
~$ rosrun tf tf_monitor
RESULTS: for all Frames

Frames:

All Broadcasters:
```

how do I make it work?
here's the broadcaster code.

```
void OdoCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& odom_in)
{
    ros::Time current_time = ros::Time::now();
    tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster;
    tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> transform;
    transform.setOrigin( tf::Vector3(odom_in->pose.pose.position.x, odom_in->pose.pose.position.y, 0.0) );
    tf::Quaternion q;
    q.setRPY(odom_in->pose.pose.orientation.z, 0, 0);
    transform.setRotation(q);

    odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(transform, ros::Time::now(), "/odom_frame", "/base_link"));
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "sensor_convert_node");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Subscriber odo_sub = n.subscribe("odom", 100, OdoCallback);

  printf("setting up laser filter\r\n");
  ros::Rate loop_rate(100);

  while (ros::ok())
  {
    ros::Time start = ros::Time::now();
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and here's the listener code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "robot_tf_listener");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  tf::TransformListener listener;
  ros::Rate r(50);
  while(n.ok()){
      tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> ident (tf::Transform(tf::createIdentityQuaternion(),
              tf::Vector3(0,0,0)), ros::Time(0), "/odom_frame");
      tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> odom_pose;
      try{
            listener.transformPose("/odom_frame",ident, odom_pose);
      }
      catch (tf::TransformException &ex) {
          ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
          ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
      }
      ros::spinOnce();
      r.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

your help is appreciated.

Ray

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171126/tf-frame-error/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure that your broadcaster has time to publish the transform before destructing. In general you should not construct it inside you callback. If you construct and destruct it immediately it will not have time to initialize it's connections and send the information before destructing.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on 2014-05-28**:
you are absolutely right!
thanks.